# noescape function error in Apache Velocity template

Tags: velocity

I am currently using noescape function in apache velocity, but it did not work and had parse error exception.

```
{
  tree: #noescape()$!{__NavTree__}#end
}
```

The error message is

```
Encountered "#end" at .... Was expecting one of:
    <EOF>
    "(" ...
    <RPAREN> ...
    <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <SET_DIRECTIVE> ...
    "##" ...
    "\\\\" ...
    "\\" ...
    <TEXT> ...
    "*#" ...
    "*#" ...
    "]]#" ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <IF_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <WORD> ...
    <BRACKETED_WORD> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <DOT> ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...
    <EMPTY_INDEX> ...
```

Does anyone have any solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The `#noescape()` directive is not a standard one, I don't know its definition. Most probably, it is not a block directive, so you should rather call it with:

`#noescape($!{__NavTree__})`